# Selecting and copying a dynamic range in excel using a VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with the dates of sales and I want to segment the last 52 weeks and 52 weeks before that. The date column is in order from oldest to most recent at the bottom. Here is what i have so far.

I HAVE EDITED THE CODE. This is what I currently have. The problem seems to be the variable l52, l104 dont always work, and stay either 1 or 0 and occasionaly take the right value. This causes temp to remain equal to 1 and thus the program breaks. Also, `Range("A2").Paste` doesnt work. What is the correct way to do this?

```
'get the last row in the date column
With Worksheets("All Data")
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    'set last_date to the most recent sales date and work out the date 52 and 104 weeks ago
    last_date = Range("D" & lRow).Value
    l52 = last_date - 365
    l104 = last_date - 730
    temp = 1
    'while the date is more than 2 years ago: Ignore
    Do While Range("D" & temp).Value < l104
        temp = temp + 1
    Loop
    'when we get the first date 2 years ago select and copy this period
    Range(("B" & temp), ("U" & lRow)).Copy
    'now work out where the 52 week sales data lies
    Do While Range("D" & temp).Value < l52
        temp = temp + 1
    Loop
    'l52 is now the number of SKU sales in the last 52 weeks
    l52 = temp
End With
'and paste it into a new worksheet
With Worksheets("Last 52")
    Range("A2").Paste
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
End With
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Is it working at all?  If not, what's the error and what line does it fail at?  Or is it running but just not doing what you want?  More detail please!

Comment: It doesn't work.

`last_date = Cells("D", lRow).Value`

it the line it breaks on. I'm trying everything to work arround it, but i need something that seperates 2 years of dates from a bulk of sales.

Comment: It may help to know that cloumn "D" has all the dates in it, and this is what im using to try seperate each year of sales.

Comment: `Cells()` takes two numbers for row and column, not a letter and a number as you have.  See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I have worked out alot over the last couple hours. At the moment it compiles and runs but doesn't do exactly what I expected. I will post an update soon.

Answer (score 0):

`last_date = Cells("D", lRow).Value` should be:
`last_date = Cells(lRow, "D").Value`

Comment: Sure. The Cells property can be used with this syntaxis to refer to a specific cell: `Cells(rowindex , columnindex)`. Notice that you had it reversed in that particular line(not in others). What you have now also works fine.

Comment: What are you trying to acomplish after the line `Range(("B" & temp), ("U" & lRow)).Copy`? It doesn´t make sense to me. Also, `l52 = temp` will not give you the number of SKU sales in the last 52 weeks. It will just be the row index number of the first sale in your 52 weeks period.

Comment: I need to copy the selection and move it to another sheet so that it can update a pivot table. I know it wont give me the number of sales but it does let me know the boundry between the 1st year and the 2nd year of data.